# Is there a service that can search for answers to general questions?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, chat-bots, question-answering

I was looking for an API service where I can ask it a general question (for example, *when was Einstein born?*) and retrieve an answer from the web.

Is there any available service to do that? Have tried Watson services, but didn't work as expected.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=when+was+Einstein+born

Comment: I need an API to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google

https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=when%20was%20Einstein%20born
and parse the response.

Wolfram ALPHA is another candidate.

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+year+was+Einstein+born&x=0&y=0

You can parse the returned html and see "Result:" div.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [dbPedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/) and/or [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page).  I think Wikidata supports [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) now, but don't quote me on that.  dbPedia definitely supports SPARQL.

If you're not interested in writing SPARQL queries by hand, you could use something like [Quepy](http://quepy.machinalis.com/). In fact, the Quepy demo demonstrates doing natural language queries against Freebase and/or dbPedia.

You could possibly also incorporate [OpenCyc](http://sw.opencyc.org/).

If you want to roll something of your own, you might want to read some / all of the research papers published by the team from the [START](http://start.csail.mit.edu/index.php) project at MIT.